# Extracting field from an XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following info in an XML file ([uploaded here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdcx785ji263yyn/projects.xml)) taken from a RestSharp response, and I only care about the 5 ID elements. I want to get these IDs into an array or list.

[image]

How can I extract them?

My attempt so far..

```
 var root = XElement.Parse(response.Content);
            var number_projects_str = root.FirstAttribute.Value;
            int number_of_projects = -1;

            if (Int32.TryParse(number_projects_str, out number_of_projects))
            {
              //create an array of size number_of_projects
              //... 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XPathSelectElements()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions.xpathselectelements%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method to select first cell from each row (which is the cell that contains ID) :

```
var Ids = root.XPathSelectElements("/ResultSet/results/rows/row/cell[1]")
              .Select(o => (string)o)
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: This looks good, but I'm too much of C# noob to make sense out of the compilation error on Select

 error CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I tried the following usings: using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;

Comment: It seems that `.Select()` comes from `System.Linq` here, so did you have `using System.Linq` ?

Comment: Thanks, that solves the compile issue, but the above code is returning an empty array. Ids should contain 5 strings.

Comment: I added a link to the full xml file in an edit to the question.

Comment: I got the desired output changing the call to XPathSelectElements("./results/rows/row/cell[1]");